# How to show text on img link hover?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've tried methods suggested by other users to users on Stackoverflow who asked more or less the same question, but in spite of employing the same methods to my code, the text ends up showing below the img.

I also followed this method: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_overlay_fade but the same thing happened.

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: ;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  text-transform: none;
  font-family: europa;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  letter-spacing: 0em;
  text-transform: none;
  color: #000;
}

.header h1 {
  background-color: ;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 0.8px;
}

.header .nav {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 0.8px;
}

.header .nav a {
  font-family: Europa;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.row {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding: ;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#text {
  font-family: europa;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  letter-spacing: 0em;
  text-transform: none;
  color: #000;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.col-md-6 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
}

.col-md-6 .wrapper {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0px solid black;
}

.col-md-6 .wrapper img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.col-md-6 .wrapper img:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .col-md-6 {
    float: none;
    background-color: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #text {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .header .nav {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .header .nav a {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .header h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .col-md-6 {
    float: none;
    background-color: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #text {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .header .nav {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .header .nav a {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .header h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  span.text-content {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: table;
    height: 150px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 150px;
  }
  span.text-content span {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .img-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .img-list {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
  }
  span.text-content {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: table;
    height: 150px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 150px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .img-list:hover span.text-content {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  span.text-content {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: table;
    height: 150px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 150px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
    transition: opacity 500ms;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Merriweather|Europa">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <h1 id="firstName">Header</h1>
      <div class="nav">
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Work</a>
        <a href="#">Photo</a>
        <a href="#">Blog</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1 id="text">Design &amp; code.</h1>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <a href="">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="img-list">

          <a href="#">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
            <span class="text-content"><span>Place Name</span></span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="wrapper">

        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>


  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you forget to set a positioning context (`position:relative`) somewhere?

Comment: Can you insert a code snippet so that we can see the output you get.

Answer (score 2):

I think your code works as you like when the screen width is less than or equal to 400px.

This is because you set the relevant styles under the media query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {

/* Your styles related to displaying the text are here*/

}
```

Note: Don't forget to close the media query. They are not closed in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

I removed all unnecessary code so it will be clear what you need to add. basically on hover we changing `.caption` opacity to `1`. is absolutely positioned within `.wrapper` and has `<span>` with text inside.

```css
.wrapper>a {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  display: block;
}

.wrapper>a>img {
  width: 100%;
}

.caption {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: opacity .4s;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
  opacity: 0;
}

.caption>span {
  font-size: 48px;
}

.wrapper > a:hover .caption {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">
      <div class='caption'>
        <span>Text on hover</span>
      </div>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

create the text you want to display relative to the location of the image link, then use this code:

```css
#wrapper .text {
  position:relative;
  bottom:30px;
  left:0px;
  visibility:hidden;
}

#wrapper:hover .text {
  visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="hover" />
    <p class="text">text</p>
</div>
```

I think I understand what you are looking for....

Comment: did you check your result? it looks broken

Comment: I am not worried about how it looks, as long as it works.

Comment: But, I see what you mean. I don't know how to fix that at the moment.